# ARC delegate issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I need to download some images from server. So I created a seperate class to handle NSURLConnection delegates. 
At the end of `didFinishDownloadingData`, I called a delegate method like  `[(id)delegate performSelectorselector(finished:) withObject:receivedData]` 
I have a view controller called `ListImages`.
I created the above connection class from ListImages class and assigned `connection.delegate = self`. After image loaded from server the method `-(void)didFinishDownloadingData:(NSData *)data;` was called successfully, and I could display that image.

My problem starts now. To handle some common tasks, I created a new class called `SharedMethods` which is a subclass of `NSObject`. I allocated connection class as

```
  Connection *conn = [[Connection alloc]init];

  conn.delegate  = self;
  [conn startDownload];  //called a method which starts nsurlconnection.
```

I am using ARC so not released that object. My applicaion got exception in method, (In Connection class)

```
  - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
        [(id)delegate performSelectorselector(finished:) withObject:receivedData]; //Got an exception in this line

   }
```

The exception was `[SharedMethods retain] message send to deallocated object`. I dont think I have released anything because I am using ARC.

There was also a problem while calling`UIAlerView` delegates inside a Class which is a subclass of NSobject. It is not called any how. My doubt is, is there any problem with using a `NSObject` sublass? Is there anything to consider when using `NSObject` sublass ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wich are the property keywords for the delegate?

Comment: I will suggest you to use @autorelease { Connection *conn = [[Connection alloc]init];

  conn.delegate  = self;
  [conn startDownload]; }

Comment: Let me know if you are still facing any issue.

Comment: When you are saying that you are writing ARC compliant code. then use assign.

Comment: @Andrea sorry , i set delegate as @property(nonatomic,assign) id<imageDownloaderDelegate> delgate;

Comment: @autorelease did not help you out?

Comment: @Praveen-K i didnt tried, today weekend, me not in office. definitely ill try that on monday

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9527/discussion-between-praveen-k-and-rakeshns)

Answer (score 2):

Using ARC doesn't mean than objects never receive the `release` method, or that they never get deallocated. It just means that **you** don't have to make explicit calls to `retain` and `release`, and that happens automatically.

The problem here is that your objects are getting deallocated because no one is owning them. Your specific problem is that `SharedMethods` is being deallocated because it's not getting retained, but I can't show you how exactly that's happening because you didn't post the relevant code.

I can, however, show you that you're not managing your `Connection` properly, and hopefully that can help you figure out what you're doing wrong with `SharedMethods`.

So you create `Connection` with `alloc init`, which with retain-release code would give it a retain count of 1, but since you're not using ARC anymore that's not really relevant. Unless some other object asserts ownership of the `Connection`, ARC will automatically insert a call to `release` to bring the retain count back to 0 (it's kind of like if ARC automatically inserted an `autorelease`).

Since you don't assign `Connection` to a `strong` or `retain` property, or put it in a collection, no other object is asserting ownership to it. So once execution reaches the end of the scope where the variable `conn` is defined, it will get released and deallocated.

So in ARC, much like in manual retain-and-release code, you still need to make sure objects are owned by some other object in order for them to stick around. The only difference is that you don't need to manually call `retain` and `release`, you just have to think about the object ownership graph—which object is owned by which other object—and make sure that any object you want to stick around is owned by some other object.

So to reiterate, you need make sure that `SharedMethods` is owned by some other object.